# Can jquery JSON AJAX ban everyone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website with AJAX to load a rss feed on the client side on page load.

If the client presses F5 too many times is it possible for the rss feed owner to ban my entire website not just that client?  So others who load the rss feed (client side) will be unable to load it?

If yes, how can they do this?  What information would they be using to ban (ip address?)?  Is there a way to prevent this banning?

Comment: How are you reading an RSS feed from a remote site without violating the same origin policy? Are you using JSONP (no worries in this case only the client will be banned)? Or did you create a server side bridge script on your domain (in this case your server IP will banned and thus all clients)?

Comment: But does the jsonp request send anything they could use to ban the other users who are doing nothing wrong?

Comment: JSONP works by a script inclusion to the target domain. So client browser sends a request to fetch this script. The Referer HTTP header is sent alongside the request. It points to the page hosting this script which is your domain. So if some user abuses they could use this information to ban your domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on a number of things. If you're loading the RSS from the client side then it's the client's IP that will be listed as the requester. The best way to do this is to request via the server side and cache the result. This will make the site faster to load and you won't have to worry about misusing someone else's resources.

Comment: Don't forget about the Referral: header. :-)

Comment: If I do this, then could my entire server be banned?

Comment: Yeah, they can look at that to ban you by domain as well (in addition to IP)

Comment: the point is to load it once, and have your website server the cached version.

Comment: If they ban the domain or even my server, will the site still get the feed because it is client side feed grab?  meaning technically, the client side ip is what is requesting the feed?

Comment: I think you're looking at this wrong. If they ban you by referrer, any request coming from your site will be blocked. That won't work for IP. In any case, the fix is quite easy in this case. Just cache locally and serve.

Comment: I SEE!  so they can ban the ip of the client (of course) AND OR the domain from referrer.  Is there a way to block referer being sent?

Comment: Not from the client side as far as I know. Is there a particular reason for you to be against a server side cache? It's quite easy to setup.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, yes. It's rather unlikely though.

If you want to do it properly, create a cache on your server for the RSS feed. Download the data and save it to your server, then let your client load that cached file instead of the remote one.

Basically that lets your server handle the requests instead of the other server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can ban you. I would guess that they would do it by not responding to any further requests from your IP address.  I would suggest that you talk with them and ask nicely to use their feed. It is always best if you can let them know about your intentions.

Comment: The "your" is the question here.  Do they ban just the client IP, the page url? my website? the whole server IP?

Comment: I regularly ban the IPs of spiders and crawlers that don't follow my robots.txt. I have had to ban the user-agent string for baidu. I also changed some common URLs that they were always crawling.